# How to create a QR code for a credit card using .NET?

Tags: .net, numbers, payment, qr-code

I want to create a QR code (image) that when decoded represents a credit card. At point of sale, such as Starbucks, would be able to decode the QR code and charge the card.

Is there a standard representation for this and potentially an option of SDKs that are available?

This is similar to Lemon Wallet, whereby they scan your credit card details and a QR code is generated. I assume the QR provides the PAN (15/16 digits), Expiry, Name and CVV.

I would be writing the code in Microsoft .NET.

Comment: That's a _very_ bad idea.  People could catch the QR code on cameras and steal the card number.

Comment: I don't see it being worse than taking a photo of a physical card where the text is plain to read... At least with QR you need some technical know-how.